# different versions in install section with travis.yml

Tags: python, travis-ci

Is it possible to define a kind of matrix in the install section?
At the moment my travis.yml looks like this:

```
python:
  - 2.7
  - 2.6
  - 3.4
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - "pip install ."
  - "pip install mock"
  - "pip install coveralls"
  - "pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But I would like to install different requirements for different python versions.

Comment: *"I would like to install different requirements for different python versions"* - how have you ended up in that position?

Comment: version 2.6 requires importlib. In version 2.7 this is included in standard lib. Thus I need to require it in 2.6. In 2.7 this would raise an error.